# In VHDL, eating whitespace & unread character from readline text buffer?

Tags: vhdl

I need a procedure that will take a text line buffer from readline and remove whitespaces between read's.... Here's what I have so far,  but I'm uncertain if its possible to "unread" a character from a line buffer to make this possible?  Any ideas what is the best why to remove the white space generically with a simple procedure?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity test1 is

end entity;

architecture beh of test1 is
```

```
    --only read white-space from linebuffer.
    -- DOESN'T WORK
    procedure read_whitespace(
        variable lline  : inout line) 
    is  
        variable c     : character;
        variable found : integer;
    begin
        c := ' ';
        found := 0;
        while (c = ' ') loop
            read(lline, c);
            found := 1;
        end loop;
        
        if (found = 1) then
            unread(lline);
        end if; 
    end procedure;
```

```
    --only read white-space from linebuffer.
    -- ALSO, DOESN'T WORK
    procedure read_whitespace2(
        variable lline  : inout line) 
    is  
        variable c      : character;
        variable found  : integer;
        variable lline2 : line;
        variable count  : integer;
        variable good   : boolean;
    begin
    
        -- First Pass: Count number of Whitespaces
        lline2 := lline;
        count  := 0;
        while true loop
            read(lline2, c, good);
            if ((not good) or (c /= ' ')) then
                exit;
            end if;
            count := count + 1;         
        end loop;
        
        report "count: " & integer'image(count);
        
        -- Second Pass: remove exact count from line buffer
        for i in 0 to count loop
            read(lline, c);
            report "pass-two:" & character'image(c);
        end loop;
        
    end procedure;
```

```
    --format: "<integer> [ns|us|ms|s]"
    procedure read_time(
        variable lline  : inout line;
        variable tvalue : out   time
    ) is
        variable c         : character;
        variable i         : integer;
        variable realvalue : real;
        variable timeunit  : string(1 to 3) := (others => ' ');
        variable good      : boolean;
        variable tvalue1   : time;
    begin            
        read(lline, realvalue, good);   -- read integer
        if (not good) then
            report "readtime: invalid number" severity failure;
        end if;     
        read_whitespace(lline);  -- <<==DOESN"T WORK
        i     := 1;
        while true loop     
            read(lline, c, good); 
            if (not good) then
                exit;
            end if;         
            timeunit(i) := c;
            i := i + 1;
            if (i = timeunit'length+1) then
                exit;
            end if;     
        end loop;               
        tvalue1 := 0 ns;
        case timeunit is        
            when "ps "  =>  tvalue1 := realvalue * 1 ps;              
            when "ns "  =>  tvalue1 := realvalue * 1 ns;                              
        end case;           
        tvalue := tvalue1;      
        report "readtime: time:" & time'image(tvalue1);     
    end procedure;
```

```
begin


process
    variable tvalue  : time;
    variable lbuf    : line;
    variable fstatus : FILE_OPEN_STATUS;
    file     fd      : text;
begin

    report "=> Testbench start";
    
    file_open(fstatus, fd, "file.txt", read_mode);
    
    while not endfile(fd) loop
        readline(fd, lbuf);
        read_time(lbuf, tvalue);
    end loop;
    
    file_close(fd); 
    
    report "=> Testbench done successfully" 
        severity failure; 
        
end process;


end architecture;
```

Comment: what is the goal here? `std.standard` already provides a read function that will remove leading white space for all standard types.

Comment: My simulator doesn’t read “time” type… (Vivado simulator) and there are white spaces between the integer and the type string.

Comment: `time` values need to be of the format "a.b ns" to read into time type. See [textio source](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/blob/master/libraries/std/textio.vhdl). There is no "unread" or rewind/seek of a file in VHDL before VHDL 2019

Comment: Edit history shows correcting question code to overcome a problem that can't be replicated lacking a [mcve] (also note the lack of file.txt contents and the process statement endlessly looping). How can the lack of reproducible error benefit future readers? Kudos for eating multiple spaces in the solution even if that isn't the only possible separator (e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008, 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters paragraph 2, note all the format effectors would be legal here, a physical literal isn't a single lexical element).

Answer (score -1):

This one works:

```
    procedure read_whitespace(
        variable lline  : inout line) 
    is  
        variable c         : character;
        variable count     : integer;
        variable pos_high  : integer;
        variable pos_low   : integer;
    begin
    
        pos_high := lline.all'high;
        pos_low  := lline.all'low;

        -- First Pass: Count number of Whitespaces
        count  := 0;
        for i in pos_low to pos_high loop
            c := lline.all(i);
            if (c /= ' ') then
                exit;
            end if;
            count := count + 1;         
        end loop;
        
        report "count: " & integer'image(count);
        
        -- Second Pass: remove exact count from line buffer
        for i in 1 to count loop
            read(lline, c);
            report "pass-two:" & character'image(c);
        end loop;
        
    end procedure;
```

Comment: minus, but i just tried it and it works.

Comment: Not my downvote but it seems like a lot of work to avoid using the `time'image` and `time'value` attributes. Don't they work in Vivado?

Comment: Actually it turns out the read time was working in vivado..  but the testbench has a bug where it was reading a string character by character....and bailing because previous read of integer leaves whitespaces that need to be consumed to get to the string..  I was just using the example of reading time to illustrate...